# How to I allow a filter inside a typescript .d file?

Tags: typescript, types, screeps

Screeps types.d.ts is throwing the error below when I try to pass a filter as a parameter to a function. According to the [screeps documentation](https://docs.screeps.com/api/#Game.market.getAllOrders) this is possible. How would I change the types file to correct this?

> Argument of type '(order: any) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '[any]'

```
var orders = Game.market.getAllOrders((order) => order.remainingAmount > 1000);
```

right now the types.d.ts file has:

```
declare class Market {
    getAllOrders([filter]): any;
    .....
```

Comment: `type Order = ?// your order type here`
`getAllOrders(f: (order: Order ) => boolean): Order[]`

Comment: @ShanonJackson that solved it. Please post it as a solution so I can mark it solved

Comment: Thanks man for offering to do that means alot

Answer (score 0):

```
type Order = ?// your order type here
getAllOrders(f: (order: Order ) => boolean): Order[]
```